# QGIS atlas feature: Storing information from coverage layer in an atlas variable

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Using QGIS` atlas feature, how can I pass information from my coverage layer to the layer's rendering engine?

At the moment, I'm abusing the *Page name* in the Layout > Atlas tab like this:

```
"country_code" || '-' || "my_custom_field"
```

In the "Labels" section in my layers I can now access this information using the variable *@atlas_pagename*.

Lets assume I have this coverage layer:

| country_code | my_custom_field |
| --- | --- |
| US | 1.0 |
| FR | 2.0 |
| LU | 3.0 |

Now, *@atlas_pagename* has these values...

```
US-1.0
FR-2.0
LU-3.0
```

... and I can use the variable in my *Data defined override* settings using something like `to_real(substr(@atlas_pagename,4))`.

The problem with this approach is every time I want to access the value of *my_custom_field*, I have to parse the needed information. And I can't use the page name variable for its intended use anymore.

So, how can I set a variable in my atlas configuration with the value of a field in my coverage layer?

Comment: Hi, your question is about how to define a new atlas variable, but can't you get the attribute of the atlas feature with _attribute(@atlas_feature, 'my_custom_field')_?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Yes and no. My question was how to access a field from the coverage layer. I somehow thought that I had to do some setup to access this data. From your comment I learned that I just can to use `attribute(@atlas_feature, 'my_custom_field')` in my _Data defined override_ expressions. Case closed. (If you provide your comment as an answer I'm happy to accept it.)

Comment: You don't even need to use `attribute()`, you can just directly reference the field name in any expressions (i.e. `"my_custom_field"`) As a bonus, that's case insensitive unlike `attribute()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to store the attributes of the coverage layer in an atlas variable, because a reference to the coverage feature of the current atlas page is stored in the *@atlas_feature* variable.

So you can call its attributes from any expression in the project, with the *attribute()* function, like:

`attribute(@atlas_feature, 'my_custom_field')`